# Use of Shared Preferences as a Highscore storage

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wanted to use Shared Preferences as a Highscore storage of my little game. But I think I didn't fully understand the Concept behind Shared Preferences.

The problem is, when the game is finished the User should be able to enter his name and save his current score (works). I tried to achieve the functionality with Shared Preferences.
When I click on my Highscore activity (where the saved highscores should be shown in a list) right after a game (user hasn't left the app) I get the last value that was saved previously (if I make more games in a row and save them it still only gives me one highscore, there has to be another mistake)(answered).

If the app was closed and I call the Highscore activity I get an exception. (open)

My Questions:

1. Does Shared Prefences only store the values while the app is running and destroy them on exit? (answered)
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I want? (answered)

The Code:

SimpleActivity.java (Where I save the High Score):

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Save & Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String m_Text = input.getText().toString();
            if(!m_Text.isEmpty() && highScoreInt > 0) {
                PreferencesManager.initializeInstance(SimpleActivity.this);
                PreferencesManager prefM = PreferencesManager.getInstance();
                prefM.setValue(m_Text, highScoreInt);
                SimpleActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

HighScoreActivity.java (here I get the error if the app is newly started, otherwise it only gives me one value, even if I saved more games)

```
public class HighScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscore);
    getHighScore();


}

public void getHighScore(){
    PreferencesManager.initializeInstance(HighScoreActivity.this);
    PreferencesManager prefM = PreferencesManager.getInstance();
    Map<String, ?> allPref = prefM.getValue();
    if(!allPref.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allPref.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

}

The Error (don't quite Understand it, because I call the initialize Method?):

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.math.mathquiz, PID: 25026
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.math.mathquiz/com.math.mathquiz.HighScoreActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PreferencesManager is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PreferencesManager is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.
   at com.math.mathquiz.PreferencesManager.getInstance(PreferencesManager.java:32)
   at com.math.mathquiz.HighScoreActivity.onCreate(HighScoreActivity.java:17)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

PreferencesManager.java

```
public class PreferencesManager {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "HighScore";
    private static PreferencesManager sInstance;
    private final SharedPreferences mPref;

    private PreferencesManager(Context context) {
        mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new PreferencesManager(context);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized PreferencesManager getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(PreferencesManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void setValue(String name, int value) {
        mPref.edit()
                .putInt(name, value)
                .commit();
    }

    public Map<String, ?> getValue() {
        Map<String, ?> all = mPref.getAll();
        return all;
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        mPref.edit()
                .remove(key)
                .commit();
    }

    public boolean clear() {
        return mPref.edit()
                .clear()
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: It stores them long-term. Shared Preferences are okay for this kind of thing since you require no security and the data is pretty basic. Share the code where your app crashes, and make sure to include the full **logcat** of the crash.

Comment: Share preferences should work in the way you want. Post code and we will try and help to find the problem. Also, post the log of the crash.

Comment: `public void setValue(String name, int value) {
        mPref.edit()
                .putLong(name, value)
                .commit();
    }` if you put value for the same key "name" twice it erase the first one, key should be unique

Comment: hmm ok, but how can i fix this if it is the same user? And he should enter his name?

Answer (score 0):

Here are answers to your questions:

1. `SharedPreferences` is a persistent storage - any data there is kept as long as the app is installed on the device.
2. There are some drawbacks to using `SharedPreferences` in your case. The prefs are a key - value store. This means that keys should be unique. With your current implementation, every time a user submits a new score with the same name, it will override the previous score by the same user. There are ways around this - add something unique to the key (like a timestamp), but then you will need additional logic to manage the keys when displaying, etc. You could also use the `SharedPreferences` to store some kind of a structure, serializes as JSON and keep the data there. But then you will have to deal with the overhead of maintaining, serializing and deserializing this structure when you need to manipulate it. I can recommend you two alternatives - a simple SQLite database that keeps track of user scores. This way you could benefit from other RDBMS benefits - sorting, querying, etc. Or, if you are developing a game, you can think of integrating Google Play Games in it. They have a leaderboard API and this is the next step in making your game more social and fitting it in the Android gaming community.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comment, I think i will give the Unique Identifier a chance. (Because i have less knowledge about databases than i have about android xD) I thought about adding Google Play Game Services in the future.